# Simplify: $3 \ln 2 - \frac{1}{2}\ln 4$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

How would you go about simplifying this equation: $$3 \ln 2 - \frac{1}{2}\ln 4$$  I am not very familiar with logarithms and how they work, the process is still confusing me.

Comment: So let us start with 3 ln 2. This is ln x for some x. Can you see what is x?

Comment: Please do not write 1/2 ln 4.  Some people will read this as 1/(2 ln 4).  You could write (1/2) ln 4, (ln 4)/2, or, preferably, $\frac {\ln 4}2$

Comment: Noted, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Adi Dani:  we avoid using double dollar signs in the title.  It takes lots of room.  In the body is fine.

Comment: o.k @Ross millikan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a\ln(b) = \ln(b^a)$ and $\ln(a)+\ln(b)=\ln(ab)$ from this you can show $\ln(a)-\ln(b) = \ln(a)+\ln(b^{-1}) = \ln(\frac{a}{b})$ which should be all you need

Comment: Thank you, the rules that you gave were helpful!

Comment: @Craig No problem, let me know what you're thinking and I'll talk you through it in the comments if you want.

Comment: I think I understand how it works now. Simplified, it should be this: ln(4)... Correct?

Comment: Yep, you've got it. @Craig

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $\ln a^b= b \ln a, \ln ab = \ln a + \ln b$

Answer (score 1):

$$3 \ln 2 - \frac{1}{2}\ln 4=3 \ln 2 - \ln 4^{\frac{1}{2}}=3 \ln 2- \ln 2=2 \ln 2$$